# Can a sentence contains one "will" and one "going to"?

Tags: grammaticality, future

Can a sentence contain “will” before the term “be going to”?

As an example,

> Wanda’s music teacher **will** be driving to the exam venue. She **is going to** pick Wanda up on her way there.

Comment: Who told you there was any rule about this?

Comment: Is this sentence correct?

Comment: That's two sentences! It's fine. I assume you mean '_on_ her way there'.

Comment: @KateBunting  I have edited the question, you can look for my edit.

Comment: @user1176409 Sorry, I had to roll back your edits. We're only allowed to ask one question at a time here. Your original question is about combining tenses, and your second was about the difference between two tenses. That second question has many answers on this site already if you search

Comment: Your verbs are not both in one sentence, but one in each of two sentences. See gotube's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your two sentences are correct, and could even be combined into one sentence:

> Wanda's music teacher **will** be driving to the exam venue, and **is going to** pick Wanda up on her way there.

Any verbs can be combined so long as their meanings make sense, unlike this bad sentence:

> *Wanda's music teacher **will** be driving to the exam venue, and **picked** Wanda up on her way there.

Comment: I have edited the question, you can look for it!